# How to determine percentile rankings for responses to for Big5 Mini-Markers test?

Tags: personality, experimental-psychology, big-five, analysis

I'm writing a big 5 personality test using Big 5 Mini Markers by Saucier, as described here: http://pages.uoregon.edu/prsnlty/SAUCIER/Saucier.Minimarkers.Full.pdf

Given that most markers have about 0.7 correlation to Big5 trait, there's a limit to the score a user can get. While the theoretical max is 72 (8 markers * 9 points), the user can only get 55 on openness to experience and 67 on others.

I want to give the user percentile score as to how high they rate.

**Do I use the theoretical max of 72 or the actual max the user can get on this test for determining low-medium-high or percentiles?** In other words, would 55 openness be equal to 100th percentile, or would 72?

I found this example of a mini marker result online:

```
Your Scores
Exraversion = 45
Agreeableness = 45
Conscientiousness = 45
Stability = 45
Openess = 45
Scores should range between 8 and 72. 
Scores from 8 to 29 could be considered "low," 
from 30 to 50 "average," 
and from 51 to 72 "high."
```

My personal calculations are as follows (by giving 1 or 9 each question that has a relevant coefficient):

```
 MIN
 openness: 6.21
 conscientiousness: 7.44
 extraversion: 8.02
 agreeableness: 7.51
 stability: 7.49

 MAX
 openness: 55.89
 conscientiousness: 66.96
 extraversion: 72.18
 agreeableness: 67.59
 stability: 67.41
```